# Schengen Visa for an Indian National Studying in Canada

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen studying in Canada. My course is getting over in April. I am planning to visit India in June, and then I am planning a vacation to Europe in July. And afterwards I am returning to Canada in the last week of July (around 22 July). My Canadian Student Visa is expiring on July 31st.

My route trip is India —-> Barcelona —> Ibiza —> Paris —-> Canada from the 15th to the 22nd of July.

As my Canadian student visa is expiring on the 31st of July, I have only 9 days left on my Canadian Student visa after returning to Canada from Schengen Area.

Will there be any problem for me to get Schengen Visa? Do they require any minimum number of days as validity of days for my student visa?

I am very worried about this. Any help or advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: This, may indeed, cause a problem that could lead to a restricted visa valid only to the 22nd of July. Everything else  would depend on your personal circumstances.

Comment: Others with better knowledge may answer, but there is a requirement for travel documents to be valid for 3 months after the intended date of departure from the Schengen zone - see 4.1.1 https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page30, which might mean a 30 April cut off in your case unless you are returning to India.